# Describe $R^×$, the invertible elements in $R$.

Tags: ring-theory

> Consider the ring $R := Q[t]_{(t)}=\{ f(t)/g(t) \mid g(0) ≠ 0\} ⊆ Q(t) = \operatorname{Frac}(Q[t])$. Then describe $R^×$, the invertible elements in $R$.

I know that Frac is a field and in this case it is a field relating to integers, however I don’t really understand how this can be related to finding the invertible elements in $R$.

Comment: $R$ is a localization of a ring: you should know a characterization of invertible elements... These are the elements which do not belong to the maximal ideal $(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

“Frac” just denote the “field of fractions”, just like when you build $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$, but here the construction is applied to $\mathbb{Q}[t]$ (the ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$).

The inverse of $f(t)/g(t)$ in $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ exists if and only if $f\ne0$ (not the zero polynomial) and is $g(t)/f(t)$. When does it belong to $\mathbb{Q}[t]_{(t)}$ according to the definition?

Comment: Thank you. After finding the invertible elements you can conclude that R is a UFD and also find the ideals of R. How can you then use this information to prove that R is a Euclidean Domain?

Comment: @Mathstudent Knowing the invertible elements doesn't really help: $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ have the same group of invertible elements; the former is a Euclidean domain, the latter isn't.